# Basic Geometry involving trapezium

Tags: geometry

In a trapezium, length of two parallel sides are $6$ cm and $10$ cm.If the oblique side has a length $1$ cm, the other oblique side must be?

A) greater than 3 units but less than 4 units

B)greater than 3 units but less than 5 units

C)less than or equal to 3 units

D)greater than 5 units but less than 6 units

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried, and where did you get stuck? P.S. Think triangle inequalities.

Comment: Hint: consider trapeziums with height tending to $0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the trapezium to consist of two right triangles abutting either end of a rectangle.

The hypotenuse of one right triangle is $1$ (given). If you let the base of it be $x$, then the other side is $\sqrt{1-x^2}$, and this is the height of the trapezium.

The base of the other right triangle is then  $4-x$, giving its hypotenuse as $\sqrt{(\sqrt{1-x^2})^2 + (4-x)^2} = \sqrt{17-8x}$

Now $-1 < x < 1$ (the two bounds correspond to where the triangle with hypotenuse $1$ becomes degenerate with its base equal to the hypotenuse, and the height of the trapezium becomes zero - hence the strict inequality signs). These bounds correspond to $\sqrt{17-8x}$ of $\sqrt{25} = 5$ and $\sqrt {9} = 3$, respectively. That (together with the monotonicity of $\sqrt{17-8x}$) gives $3 < \sqrt{17-8x} < 5$. Therefore $B$ is the correct choice.

Comment: Edited my answer, previous one contained an error where I assumed the minimum value $x$ could take was zero.

Answer (score 1):

Four lengths $a, c, b, d$ can constitute the consecutive sides of a non-parallelogram trapezoid with a and $b$ parallel only when

$| d − c | < | b − a | < d + c$ . 
(wikipedia)

Edit: If I want to calculate it I get a different result $c=\sqrt{\sin^2 \alpha +4^2}$ [image] with $a=1$, $b=6$ and $d=10$. I start with $h=1 \sin \alpha$ and then using Pythagoras....

Wikipedia: $|d-1|< 4 < d + 1$

Own Calculation: $4 \leq d \leq \sqrt{17}$

Comment: Of course it's $c= \sqrt{\sin^2 \alpha + x^2}$, because we didn't know what $x$ is.

Answer (score 0):

A little Geometry.

Refer to the above drawing:

Let's label corners: left bottom $A$, advance counter clockwise $B, C$ and $D$.

1)Draw side $DC$, called $b$ in the drawing.

2)Draw a circle about $D$ with radius $a (= 1)$.

Consider the parallel line $AB (=d)$. The locus of $A$ is on this  circle.

In other words consider the family  of parallel lines $AB$ with endpoint $A$ that lie on the circle about $D$ with radius 1.

$\angle ADC$ =: $ \theta$.

Pick any $\theta$, I.e. any point $A$ and draw a line parallel to $AD (= a)$ through $C$.

Let the intersection with $AB$  be $B'$.

$AB'CD$ is a parallelogram.

Opposite sides are equal. Hence length $CB'$ = 1.

Consider $\triangle B'BC$.

1) Length $B'B$ = 10 - 6 =  4.

2) Length $CB'$  = 1.

3) $\angle BB 'C = (180 - \theta)$.

$x$: = length $CB$.

Cosine Rule:

$x^2 =$

$1^2 + 4^2 - 2×4×1×cos (180 - \theta)$.

$x^2 = 16 + 1 - 8×cos(180 - \theta)$.

$- 1  \lt cos (180 - \theta) \lt +1$,

to make it a trapezoid.

Inequality:

$17 - 8 \lt x^2 \lt 17 + 8 $,

$9 \lt x^2 \lt 25$.

$Finally$ :

$3 \lt x \lt 5$.